# In-page updates don't add the red background to deleted posts

Tags: bug, design

While investigating an oddly formatted post, QAdp fixed the formatting and then immediately deleted the post in question. When I clicked the notification to reload the post, I saw this:

[image: lolocaust]

The red background didn't load! Oh no!

Comment: (The original trollface was a sad display of epic markdown fail, so I fixed it for him)

Comment: Formatting bugs should always be fixed, even if it's spam.

Comment: You should probably provide a link to the post in question.

Comment: @Wipqozn What good would that do? Loading the page it does have the correct background, it's only the in-page update that doesn't work, and that can't be replicated.

Comment: @QAdley Oh, okay. I thought it wasn't working even if you reloaded the page.